# How to export correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to import `test.js` in `main.js`,I suffered some following errors..

I totally confused how to fix it and how to export correctly..

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

`test.js`

```
export default class Test {

    constructor(quizData){
        this._quizzes = quizData.results;
        this._correctAnswersNum = 0;
    }
    
    getNumOfQuiz(){
        return this._quizzes.length;
    }
}
```

`main.js`

```
import Test from './test.js';
// require('./quiz.js')

(()=>{
      
      const url = "/quiz-data";
      
      console.log("main.js was loaded");
      
      fetch(url)
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); })
      .then(quiz => displayQuiz(quiz,1))

})();
```

Comment: It seems that your env't doesn't support ES6 imports

Comment: Where are you running this code, Node environment? Also `export` (es6) and `module.exports` (commonjs) are different module systems.

Comment: NodeJS uses CommonJS for imports/exports, that's what the `modules.exports` is. JavaScript's module syntax uses the `export` keyword and should be supported in node versions >= 12.

Answer (score 0):

Remove module.exports = Quiz; from your code.
It will start working
Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export for es6 import and export.

Comment: After remove, it still warn same errors.. I guess there is another point of this error.

Comment: Does your environment support es6 import and export? If not then please follow the link to know how to do it correctly.https://medium.com/@zachgavin/module-exports-and-loading-es5-to-es6-a33ac592989c